# Parse Video Upload - Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional Value

Tags: swift, video, parse-platform, option-type

I am trying to upload a video to Parse

If I just try to upload the video like so:

```
let videoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
let videoFile = PFFile(name: "video.mov", data: videoData)
videoUploadObject["Video"] = videoFile
```

I will receive the error. I tried to remove this by running something like the following.

```
Main.sharedMain.userVideoOutputURL
```

returns:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3B78A154-4340-432B-817A-2857EBA8064A/tmp/video.mov
```

Here is my full code:

```
let url = Main.sharedMain.userVideoOutputURL!

    if let videoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {

        let videoFile = PFFile(name: "video.mov", data: videoData)
        videoUploadObject["Video"] = videoFile


        print("Video File \(videoFile)")


    } else {
        print("Else")
    }
```

Else is always printed? What can I do to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: I don't get how you could get `Else` printed _and_ an error `Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional Value` thrown using just the code you posted.

Comment: @paulvs Sorry! I have updated my question!

Comment: The path looks wrong, it should be an absolute path such as `file:///Users/paulvs/.....`. Everything points to a bad path or file name, `NSData(contentsOfURL:)` is returning `nil’.

Comment: @paulvs You are exactly right! Are you sure why I am getting the wrong URL from `didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL`

Comment: It looks like it returns a relative path, it's not incorrect, it just needs to be appended to the absolute path it's related to.

Comment: @paulvs Thank you so much! Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Currently this is how I am starting the URL `let outputFilePath  =
                NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent("video.mov")
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL looks fine (iOS doesn't use "/User/blah/blah/blah" for applicaion storage).

My first thought would be to check the data is writing correctly. NSData has a "writeToFile: options:" method that returns a bool. This will return false if writing has failed, and also throw an error which should give you some extra information.

```
let url = <YOUR_URL>
do {
    // put your options in here
    try data.writeToURL(url, options: NSDataWritingOptions.DataWritingAtomic)
} catch _ {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

If writing has succeeded, then you'll want to try loading the data using "contentsWithUrl: options:". This also throws an error if it fails, and so using the "localisedDescription" property of the thrown error object you should be able to get to the bottom of why it isn't loading.

```
let url = <YOUR_URL>
var data: NSData? = nil
do {
    // put your options in here
    try data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingUncached)
} catch _ {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Hope that helps :)